# Dynamic Input Values Not Recognized By Php

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table where i dynamically add rows with input fields based on the user requirement. These input fields are stored as an array so that looping over them can get the values in each row to insert into the db. The issue is that only the first "static" row from the table is recognized in the array. Every other dynamic input field is not stored in the input array when submitted. A snippet of the table code is

```
  <tr><td><input type=number name=minimum[] required></input></td><td><input type=number name=maximum[] required></input></td>   <td><input type=number name=overall[] required></input>    
   <td><?php echo $formular;?></td></tr>
    </tbody><tfoot><tr><td colspan="25"><div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>  
      </div></td></tr></tfoot></table></div></form>
```

The jquery code to add an extra row is:

```
<script>
            $(window).load(function(){
     $(function () {
    var rowv="<tr><td><input type=number name=minimum[] required></input></td>      
     <td><input type=number name=maximum[] required></input></td><td><input 
   type=number name=overall[] required></input></td><td><?php echo $formular;?>
   </td></tr>";         

    $("#addRow").click(function () {
        var row = $(rowv);
        $("#mt > tbody").append(row);
    });
});
});

    </script>
```

The (abbreviated) php code to process the array is :

```
foreach($_POST['fi'] as $key=>$value){


                    $sql="insert into band(fi) values ('$value')";

  }
```

Only the first row is being inserted. Any row that added dynamically is not submitted to the post array. How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Create your input field like this and then append it to the form and then try.

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "text";
            input.name = "minimum[]";
            input.required = "true";
$("#testForm").append(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery syntax seems incorrect. Change that click function to this:

```
$("#addRow").click(function () {
    $("#mt > tbody").append(
        "<tr>" +
          "<td><input type='number' name='minimum[]' required></td>" +
          "<td><input type='number' name='maximum[]' required></td>" +
          "<td><input type='number' name='overall[]' required></td>" +
          "<td><?php echo $formular;?></td>" +
        "</tr>"
    );
});
```